# Deterministic finite automata that accepts the only the string "aabb"

Tags: turing-machines, automata, finite-automata

Lets construct a DFA over{a,b} That accepts only the string "aabb" in it.
My problem with this video is that the tutor has 
moved arrow from state D to B why didn't he set a self loop on D .Im really helpless .

[Move forward to minute 11](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_2cKtLkdwnc&list=PLBlnK6fEyqRgp46KUv4ZY69yXmpwKOIev&index=6)

Comment: You should improve the title. It is too broad. Please take some time to improve it.

Comment: The question should be self contained, could you transcribe relevant part?

Comment: @fade2black may I start a conversation with you if that doesn't bother you ?I'm new to this website sorry for posting answers instead of comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your purpose is to detect a substring $aabb$. When the FA is in state $D$ it already has read $aab$ (pay attention that in order to get to $D$ from the start state the FA must read $aab$ or $a\dots aab$). While in state $D$ there are two possible inputs: $a$ or $b$. If it reads $a$ it enters the state $B$ because it already has $a$ (it remains to read $abb$). On $b$ it enters the accept state. If on $a$ it stays on $D$ then it would accept a wrong string, for example, $aabab$ which does not contain $aabb$ as a substring. In other words, on $a$ you should send it back to the state $B$ as if FA switches from state $A$ into state $B$.

Comment: @user93 Your proposed FA is not correct. Please see the related video.

Comment: the question description says that it needs to only accept string "aabb" not string with sub-string "aabb"

Comment: @user93 it says "...That accepts only the string "aabb" in it.". You can also watch the video.

Comment: I didn't see that coming I have added a new DFA

Comment: @user93 it is still wrong. The back-transition should go to the second state from the left. Also label all states like in the video. You can draw the DFA exactly like in the video.

Comment: diagram corrected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67561/discussion-between-user93-and-fade2black).